# Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: python, django, httpurlconnection

while installing anything through pip i m getting this error ,
 Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
I was installing django through pip command i.e pip install django and i got this error :

```
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, 
status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to 
proxy.', 
NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection 
object at 0x04135910>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] 
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused 
it',))': /simple/django/
Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, 
status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to 
proxy.', 
NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection 
object at 0x04135850>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] 
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused 
it',))': /simple/django/
Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, 
status=None)) 
after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', 
NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection 
object at 0x04135930>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] 
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused 
it',))': /simple/django/
Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, 
status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to 
proxy.', 
NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection 
object at 0x04135770>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] 
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused 
it',))': /simple/django/
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, 
status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to 
proxy.', 
NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection 
object at 0x04135870>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] 
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused 
it',))': /simple/django/
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django (from 
versions: )
No matching distribution found for django
```

Comment: Looks like a firewall issue to me. 
if that is the issue try doing this.

pip install pygame‑1.9.3‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl .

Comment: you can download the package from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: i used this command  pip install pygame‑1.9.3‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl , got this error - Requirement 'pygame‑1.9.3‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
pygame‑1.9.3‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl is not a valid wheel filename.

Comment: try pip install --upgrade pip and then running the commans

Comment: also, just in case, rename file to simple name like abc.whl and then run the command with updated name, that way you can be sure, you are not making mistake with filename.

Answer (score -1):

if you are using windows, just run cmd as administrator. This might solve your problem.

Answer (score -3):

1. Set proxy settings like this:

   ```
   import telebot

   **from telebot import apihelper**

   bot = telebot.TeleBot( tkn )

   **apihelper.proxy = {
     'https': 'socks5://swcbbabh:зфыыцщкв@ley.vivalaresistance.info:3306'
   }**


   @bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
   ...
   ```
2. Update gunicorn, requests, and PySocks.
3. Restart the application.

Comment: ain't going to run that stuf bro, suspicious af